# How to create buttons in openWRT Luci Lua code

Tags: lua, openwrt, luci

I need to create one butten in the header of OpenWrt UI. how can i achive this using Luci Lua code.

Comment: you can add button in the view instead of lua controllers.

Comment: Did we tried to add normal button and trigger Lua code?